# How to sort a CSV file using Windows command line?

Tags: csv, sorting, cmd

I have a file like this:

```
9007,5001,800085,,100,40.00,,,,,20170923,,,8157,60400,,,,,,,5001,,,,,51815720718
9007,5001,9995,,100,40.00,,,,,20170930,,,8157,60400,,,,,,,5001,,,,,51815720718
9007,5001,35787654,,370,2.00,,,,,20170923,,,8157,60405,,,,,,,5001,,,,,51815720718
2001,5001,557,,370,4.25,,,,,20170930,,,8157,60405,,,,,,,5001,,,,,51815720718
9007,5001,657,,704,3.75,,4,,,20170930,,,8157,60400,,,,,,,5001,,,,,51815720718
```

And I have to sort the file like this:

```
2001,5001,557,,370,4.25,,,,,20170930,,,8157,60405,,,,,,,5001,,,,,51815720718
9007,5001,657,,704,3.75,,4,,,20170930,,,8157,60400,,,,,,,5001,,,,,51815720718
9007,5001,800085,,100,40.00,,,,,20170923,,,8157,60400,,,,,,,5001,,,,,51815720718
9007,5001,9995,,100,40.00,,,,,20170930,,,8157,60400,,,,,,,5001,,,,,51815720718
9007,5001,35787654,,370,2.00,,,,,20170923,,,8157,60405,,,,,,,5001,,,,,51815720718
```

I had used `sort FileName` command but that is of no use because I am getting result like:

```
2001,5001,557,,370,4.25,,,,,20170930,,,8157,60405,,,,,,,5001,,,,,51815720718  
9007,5001,35787654,,370,2.00,,,,,20170923,,,8157,60405,,,,,,,5001,,,,,51815720718
9007,5001,657,,704,3.75,,4,,,20170930,,,8157,60400,,,,,,,5001,,,,,51815720718
9007,5001,800085,,100,40.00,,,,,20170923,,,8157,60400,,,,,,,5001,,,,,51815720718
9007,5001,9995,,100,40.00,,,,,20170930,,,8157,60400,,,,,,,5001,,,,,51815720718
```

Can anyone help me on this task please?

Comment: You know that JavaScript and cmd are two COMPLETELY different environments? JS is in a browser -> high-level and cmd is very near to the system -> low-level

Comment: Does your `.csv` file have an unshown header?

Answer (score -1):

Javascript is used to manipulate DOM Elements. CMD and Javascript are two different dimensions.

Comment: Windows supports scripting with JavaScript, perhaps this is what the OP meant. And JavaScript can do much more than just DOM, only to mention NodeJS. And no: I am _not_ the downvoter